# Get specific value from each group after partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table -

```
ID | Type | Val0 | Val1 | Group | Creation_date
1  |  A   |  V1  | Val1 | G1    | 24sep, 2011
2  |  A   |  V1  | Val2 | G1    | 27oct, 2008
3  |  A   |  V2  | Val3 | G2    | 19oct, 2003
4  |  B   |  X1  | Xal1 | G3    | 15 dec, 2001
5  |  B   |  X2  | Xal2 | G4    | 15 dec, 2000
6  |  B   |  X2  | Xal3 | G4    | 15 dec, 1990
7  |  C   |  X3  | Xal4 | G5    | 23Dec, 2001
```

I want to keep only the latest values for a particular type and extract out values which are old but not belong to group with which the latest item is associated. So, for above table, I want these items to be extracted out - Val3, Xal2, Xal3 which i can delete later.

since A is having the latest value as Val1 which belongs to group G1, B is having the latest value as Xal1 and C is having the latest value as Xal4.

Can anybody suggest me how i can do this using SQL?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.  I

Comment: Group is a reserved word in Oracle, you shouldn't use it as a column name.

Comment: What if you had one more row for Type = 'A', where Group = 'G2' but Val1 = 'Val2'? That is, the same value, 'Val2', appears for both group G1 and G2? Should it be selected (for deletion later), or should it be left alone? (Or is that situation guaranteed by your business rules not to occur?)

Comment: Hey , Each item in Val1 can belong to one group only.  One value belonging to 2 groups will never occur in my use-case.

Comment: Hey, Now i have a use case where same value can appear in 2 groups. I want to pick that time if that is not the latest item in any other group. Can anyone tell how i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`  :

```
SELECT p.type,p.val1 FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.type ORDER BY t.max_d DESC) as rnk
    FROM (SELECT s.Type,s.Val1,MAX(s.creation_date) as max_d
          FROM YourTable s
          GROUP BY s.type,s.val1) t) p
WHERE p.rnk > 1
```

Comment: The OP did not want to pick up `val1` if it was part of the same group (G1) as the group of the most recent row. So for example Val2 should not be selected. In your query there is no reference to the "group" column whatsoever, so it is not possible for it to be correct.

Comment: Different people may have different criteria for upvotes and downvotes. Mine for downvoting is solutions that pretty clearly are not going to satisfy the requirements. In this case the requirement was pretty clearly stated (in my opinion), and your query doesn't even refer to the `group` column anywhere, so seeing that it won't work is trivial. I use my upvotes and downvotes to try to make this forum a more useful place. This kind of solutions, especially from experienced members, are not helpful at all.

Comment: Leave aside the fact that this question is poorly formatted, and without expected out put unless you read the question while concentrating , you will not understand what the OP actually want. You can also leave aside the fact that he asked similar question on other column yesterday, which I automatically assumed is connected and has the same logic. Answered that lacks a tiny part for the actual solution should not be down voted, not up voted, but defiantly not down voted.

Comment: You have a simple solution - since your Answer does not actually address the OP's question (as you can easily agree after I pointed out the problem), you can simply delete your Answer! However, from your reaction I assume you are happy for people to upvote your Answer, which is clearly not correct.

Comment: Hah yea, please give me 8 more reputation!! Pleasee . I intend to fix this answer mor**.

Comment: Oh and as to "In my opinion it was very clear" , you first edited my answer - you didn't see anything wrong with it and you asked the OP 30 minutes ago what happens in this case. So please, cut the crap, this question wasn't clear at all. @mathguy

Comment: Love your language, too. I edited your piece of crap (see, I can use it too, but I will stop now - it doesn't belong here) because you called one of your subqueries "t" but then referred to it as "s" - that is the only change I made. And the question I asked the OP has nothing to do with the fact he definitely wanted groups to be considered. I asked for clarification on a special situation which may not even happen in his real life situation. Delete this incorrect answer; if you are able to fix it, publish your answer then (although Gordon has already done so - it's not clear what you can add)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`.  No aggregation is necessary:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.type order by creation_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

However, you want the values that are not in this group.  That is, you want the values from `val1` where `seqnum` is not 1.  This would be:

```
select t.val1
from (select t.*, min(seqnum) over (partition by t.type, t.group) as min_seqnum -- DON'T USE group FOR COLUMN NAMES!
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by t.type order by creation_date desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where min_seqnum <> 1;
```

Comment: @Neha - If you need to exclude values that may appear in two groups, both the most recent one and an older one, this solution will not work. However, you can `select t.val1` (or more likely `t.type, t.val1`) from your original table where min_seqnum = 1 (using Gordon's notation) and use it as a subquery. For example, `select t.type, t.val1 from YOURTABLE minus [Gordon's subquery here, select t.type, t.val1 from ... , but with the last row changed to min_seqnum = 1]`.

Comment: hey..thanks..This solution works for me..But if i want to exclude those items which appear in 2 groups, most recent and an older one, is there any better solution ? I can use subquery option provided by you, but that will make the query to take longer to run..!!

Comment: @Neha . . . All methods that I can think of require a subquery (or something more complicated).